# "DataContext is not set" message on main window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datacontext

I'm getting the XLS1106 "DataContext is not set" message on my main window XAML in Visual Studio. As far as I can tell, I haven't used anything related to that and nothing is broken. I would just supress the message, but I'm not sure why it's there.

Here is my whole XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="MyWindow" x:Class="Whiteboard.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Whiteboard"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Untitled - CFWhiteboard" Height="450" Width="800" MouseDown="WindowMouseDown" MouseMove="WindowMouseMove" KeyDown="WindowKeyDown" KeyUp="WindowKeyUp" Icon="icons8-interactive-whiteboard-100.png" Loaded="WindowLoaded" Closing="WindowClosing">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <FrameworkElement x:Key="CursorRectangle" Cursor="Resources/Cursors/rectangle.cur"/>
            <FrameworkElement x:Key="CursorSquare" Cursor="Resources/Cursors/lockrect.cur"/>
            <FrameworkElement x:Key="CursorEllipse" Cursor="Resources/Cursors/ellipse.cur"/>
            <FrameworkElement x:Key="CursorCircle" Cursor="Resources/Cursors/lockellipse.cur"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: Add `DataContext = this;` to constructor in xaml.cs. Btw, I'm not sure, what's the original reason of that. Maybe code analyzer warns you. It looks like a warning not error. Learm something about Data Bindings, it's a cool feature of WPF.

Comment: @aepot Perfect, that fixed the message. I'm still not sure why it's happening to begin with.

Comment: You can't use WPF as intended without Data Bindings. Writing code in xaml.cs is not a thing to do (it's too hard to make a software this way). Also some read about MVVM programming pattern can show you something new and definetly useful. `DataContext` would become your close friend then. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is a false positive. The fix for the problem is available in the latest preview version of Visual Studio:

> Microsoft Solution - Bhavya Udayashankar [MSFT]  Closed - Fixed ···
>
> A fix for this issue has been released! Install the most recent preview release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. Thank you for providing valuable feedback which has helped improve the product.

See issue [*"XLS1106 on virgin C# WPF .Net application"*](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/xls1106-on-virgin-c-wpf-net-application/1215482) on the Visual Studio Developer Community site.

In the simplest applications without any data bindings set up, there is no need for a data context to be set, and the warning given can be safely ignored.

Note that you should **NOT** follow the advice of the comment above telling you to add `DataContext = this;` to the window's constructor for real-world applications. Write a proper view model object type, and create an instance of that to set as your `DataContext` reference.